# Inner query not throwing error in postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql, inner-query

There is a scenario in which we are retrieving some result from inner query and using the result to perform some operation

```
create table test1(key integer,value varchar)

insert into test1 values(1,'value 1');
insert into test1 values(2,'value 2');
insert into test1 values(3,'value 3');
```

second table as

```
create table test2(key1 integer, valuein varchar);


insert into test2 values (2,'value inside is 2');
insert into test2 values (4,'value inside is 4');
insert into test2 values (5,'value inside is 5');
```

the below query is giving result but in my view it should give an error

```
select * from test1 where key in 
(select key from test2)
```

because key column does not exist in test2 table.

but it is giving result in postgres

but when run in oracle it is giving error as

> ```
> ORA-00904: "KEY": invalid identifier
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct behavior as specified in the SQL standard. The inner query has access to all columns of the outer query - and because test1 has a column named `key` (which, btw is a horrible name for a column) the inner select is valid.

See these discussions on the Postgres mailing list:

http://postgresql.nabble.com/BUG-13336-Unexpected-result-from-invalid-query-td5850684.html

Comment: but the same in oracle is giving error as when same query is running in it . so either one of the data base oracle or postgres  is wrong in implementing the same                                                                                                           ORA-00904: "KEY": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: @user3247573 Works for me in Oracle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/baf80e/1  Which (**exact**) Oracle version are you using?